Why is it so hard to get a new invention patented
Can I get my invention patented and pay later . Anyone can tell my chair electrical sports chair for disabled kids will make money . I was homeless when I came up with this great design that works because I build a ruff prototype. Now I've got to try to save money to buy the actual parts so it's more professional. This chair got me to want to live life quite drugs and to change my life around . To help people. it came from the streets and I even found everything I need to build a ruff prototype to make sure it worked from the trash.ive got natural skills i guess from everything ive learned over the years . I just borrowed a welder and now I can weld. I don't have any help and this chair should be available for kids to use .it will make there life a lot better than any other mobility scooter or electric wheelchair out there . It's very unique and special. It's also from the streets so I'm making it so it can give back to the streets.it has a real life purpose to help where help is desperately needed all over the world .can you point me in the right direction or can anyone help .

You should look into the USPTO Pro Bono Program, here:
https://www.uspto.gov/patents/basics/using-legal-services/pro-bono/patent-pro-bono-program
If you’re an inventor or small business owner, you may be eligible for free legal assistance in preparing and filing a patent application. The Patent Pro Bono Program is a nationwide network of independently operated regional programs that matches volunteer patent attorneys and agents with financially underresourced inventors and small businesses to provide free legal assistance in securing patent protection.
You can go through that list and find a program that is close to you, if you want to meet in-person with a practitioner, or you can look for programs that offer virtual consultation.
You can also look for a local/virtual Law School Clinic program:
https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/ip-policy/public-information-about-practitioners/law-school-clinic-1
The Law School Clinic Certification Program includes over 60 participating law school clinics that provide legal services pro bono to the public, including to inventors, entrepreneurs, and small businesses. Participating law school clinics provide patent and/or trademark legal services to qualified members of the public who are accepted as a client of a clinic. Each participating law school has requirements for accepting new clients and accepts new clients at their discretion.
Additionally, you likely qualify as a micto-entity, which means you can get a 75% reduction on most USPTO fees.


Can I get my invention patented and pay later [?]

Generally not. The vast majority of patent filings do not involve inventions that turn out to be commercially viable, and so patent practitioners usually need money up front to work on a patent application. There is a slight chance that you might be able to find some pro bono assistance with your patent application.

design that works because I build a ruff prototype [...] to buy the actual parts so it's more professional

If you have even a rough prototype working, that may be sufficient to determine what about it is novel and non-obvious over the prior art and you may already have enough material for a patent filing. A "professional" prototype is usually not necessary (for a patent filing that is; it may be necessary for convincing investors to invest).
(The full answer regarding prototypes is that even a "rough" prototype isn't strictly required, but it can help to make sure that what is being patented is actually feasible to implement and meets all the performance critera that today's dynamic marketplace expects.)
I suggest to try to keep your idea confidential (hopefully you have been doing this up to now) and discuss with a patent practitioner at the earliest opportunity.
